# Memory stream out of memory exception when filesize greter than 4 gb

Tags: c#, memorystream

I am having a problem with memory stream. I am getting a exception of out of memory exception. How to handle this.

```
var file = VC.ReadStream(filename, true);
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
file.CopyTo(memoryStream);
var fileContentBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
memoryStream = null;
LogUtil.Log(LogUtil.LogType.INFO, String.Format("File size: {0} bytes", fileContentBytes.Length));
var enc = new UTF8Encoding();
var filecontent = enc.GetString(fileContentBytes);
```

Comment: 32 bit or 32 bit program? YOu do know that there is a hard limit on memory for 32 bit programs? Have you looked into avoiding memory stream and using a MMF (Memory Mapped File)?

Answer (score 3):

First, the size of `String` is *restricted to 2Gb*, and that's why

```
  var filecontent = enc.GetString(fileContentBytes);
```

will be *OutOfMemory* exception. Next, you've got a giant overhead at

```
  var fileContentBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
```

Since both `memoryStream` and `fileContentBytes` array are about **4 Gb** 
they are **8 Gb** total. Yet another issue: when working with `IDisposable`
you are supposed to *dispose* the instances:

```
  using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
    file.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    var fileContentBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    ...
  }
```

If your task is to put down the *file's size* into a log you don't need to read the file at all:

```
  long length = new System.IO.FileInfo(filename).Length;
  LogUtil.Log(LogUtil.LogType.INFO, String.Format("File size: {0} bytes", length));
```

When working with file content use `FileStream` class istead of `MemoryStream` since it works with memory chunks (Kbs in size, usually 4 or 8 Kb)

Answer (score 0):

Reading a so big file at once in memory is not a so god idea. Since this is a text file you should read it and process line by line, using `FileStream.ReadLine()`. If it is a bynary file, find some chunking strategy. If you really can't do so, try with some Memory Mapping technique.

Answer (score 0):

I can also advice you to you the `StreamReader.ReadLineAsync()` Method.